# PHP: Sum list of values

Tags: php, list, sum

I have a list of information like this...

```
No. Customer Bank_Name Amount
-----------------------------
1.  AAA      Bank A    100 
2.  BBB      Bank B    200 
3.  CCC      Bank A    500 
4.  DDD      Bank C    150 
-----------------------------
Total                  950
```

How can I sum this information for each bank, using PHP, so the result looks like this...

```
No. Bank_Name Total
-------------------
1.  Bank A    600 
2.  Bank B    200 
3.  Bank C    150 
-------------------
```

Comment: This would be a great use for a GROUP BY in a database.  Where is this data stored?  If it must be done in PHP, for whatever reason, what does the data-structure look like in PHP?

Comment: I assume Bank B should have 1000 in your result?

Comment: You're right: Bank B should have 1000; thanks again.

Comment: Your edited question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 3):

If it's in a database... something like:

```
SELECT bank, SUM(amount) as `sum`
FROM customers
GROUP BY bank
ORDER BY bank
```

Comment: I'm using query SELECT for my field data which one is bank name and amount on it. At my page I'm listed all customer information then at the bottom of page I make summary of each bank and sum amount for each bank (unique).

Comment: @user394461 Please update your question with this information.

Comment: My page should shown information like this:<br>

No.   Name  Bank     Amount <br>
--------------------------- <br>
1.     AAA   Bank A    100  <br>
2.     BBB   Bank B    200  <br>
3.     CCC   Bank A    500  <br>
4.     DDD   Bank C    150  <br>
----------------------------<br>
Total                  950  <br><br>

Summary<br><br>

    Bank Name      Total  <br>
------------------------- <br>
1.     Bank A    600  <br>
2.     Bank B    200  <br>
3.     Bank C    150  <br>
------------------------- <br>

Comment: @user394461 Please, update the question itself -- you can edit it -- and use the code formatting features.

Comment: Really sorry, i'm just did it today.Thanks.